# creating a basic bank system, keyword 'this' in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

My assignment is to create a bank contains multiple accounts. The bank needs a method that will return the total sum of money in the accounts. It also needs an addAccount method that will enroll a new account at the bank and add it to the array of accounts. You should be able to deposit or withdraw from an account to change the balance. Ensure that the accounts cannot have negative values. Write a 'transfer' on the bank that allows you to transfer amounts between two accounts.

My problem is to find a way to print out each user's details (name, balance). I feel that there's some kind of link that I've missed by applying keyword `this`. 
Here's my code:

```
var account = function (name, balance){

  account.name = name;
  account.balance = balance;

  account.deposit = function (depositAmount) {
    newBalance = account.balance - depositAmount;
    console.log("Your balance is now " + newBalance);
    if (newBalance <= 0) {
      console.log("You have insufficient funds!!!");
    }
  };

  account.withdraw = function (withdrawAmount){
    newBalance = account.balance - withdrawAmount;
    console.log("Your balance is now " + newBalance);
    if (newBalance <= 0) {
      console.log("You have insufficient funds!!!");
    }

  };

  account.transfer = function (transferAmount){
//got stuck here
  }

  console.log("Name: " + name + "; Balance: " + balance);
}


var AustinAccount = new account ("Austin", 500);
var KateAccount = new account ("Kate", 10000);
var GingerAccount = new account ("Ginger", 70000000);
var OreoAccount = new account ("Oreo", 900000000);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is the code working? Did you get any errors?

Comment: Yes I found all the answers very helpful. I guess I had trouble understanding how to use the key word this. I'm still learning this is my first week doing javascript. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Tips and tricks

Let's start from the basics:

constructors should start with capital letters:

```
function Account(name, balance) {

}
```

Then, as @Ibar said, you should use `this` to refer to the constructor instance instead of calling it by name.

```
function Account(name, balance) {
  this.name = name;
  ...
}
```

Then, you can access any instance property with:

```
var account = new Account('Hey', 100);
console.log(account.name);
```

Also, the proper way to define methods of a constructor is:

```
function Account(name, balance) {

}

Account.prototype.deposit = function(arg) {

}
```

---

## Working script

Here you find a working script, I have added two private methods (`_isPositive` and `_isAllowed`) that check if the given amount is positive, and if there will be enough funds in the account after a given transaction.

```js
function Account(name, balance) {
  this.name = name;
  this.balance = balance;
}

Account.prototype.deposit = function(amount) {
  if (this._isPositive(amount)) {
    this.balance += amount;
    console.info(`Deposit: ${this.name} new balance is ${this.balance}`);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Account.prototype.withdraw = function(amount) {
  if (this._isAllowed(amount)) {
    this.balance -= amount;
    console.info(`Withdraw: ${this.name} new balance is ${this.balance}`);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Account.prototype.transfer = function(amount, account) {
  if (this.withdraw(amount) && account.deposit(amount)) {
    console.info(`Transfer: ${amount} has been moved from ${this.name} to ${account.name}`);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}


Account.prototype._isPositive = function(amount) {
  const isPositive = amount > 0;
  if (!isPositive) {
    console.error('Amount must be positive!');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

Account.prototype._isAllowed = function(amount) {
  if (!this._isPositive(amount)) return false;

  const isAllowed = this.balance - amount >= 0;
  if (!isAllowed) {
    console.error('You have insufficent funds!');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

const a = new Account('a', 100);
const b = new Account('b', 0);


output.innerText += `before:  a: ${a.balance}, b: ${b.balance}\n`;

a.transfer(100, b);

output.innerText += `after:  a: ${a.balance}, b: ${b.balance}\n`;
```

```html
<div id=output></div>
```

---

## Improvements

You may then further improve your script adding a log of the transactions, and maybe even a way to manage different banks

```
const fooBank = new Bank('foo');
const fezAccount = new fooBank.Account('fez', 0);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks! Do you mind explaining what is prototype and why did you use it in this case?

Comment: I've also noticed that instead of using 'var', you used 'const' instead. Are there any differences?

Comment: `const` is a new feature of JS, it allows to define constants that can't be edited once defined. About `prototype`, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype.

Remember to mark the answer as correct please.

Comment: About marking the answers, as I'm very new... Can you only mark one answer correct? I went along to mark every correct answer, it seems that the previous green ticks went back to grey.

Comment: Yes you can mark only one as correct (the best one), you can still give points (with the up arrow) to the ones you liked

Answer (score 1):

Inside `account` function, you should replace `account` by `this`.

```
var account = function (name, balance){
     this.name = name; 
     this.balance = balance; 

     this.deposit = function (depositAmount) {
         ...
     }
}
```

After creating an `account` object, you can call  `AustinAccount.balance` to retrieve info about your object.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/jiheqotaye/edit?js,console

Everything Fez said is exactly what you need to consider when writing an easy-to-understand constructor.

With the `transfer` method; you want to check that the passed in `account` is an instance of the same constructor. Then check that the `withdraw` is successful, then proceed with the deposit.

```
Account.prototype.transfer = function (transferAmount, account){
  if (account instanceof Account) {
    if (this.withdraw(transferAmount)) {
      account.deposit(transferAmount);
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("An error occured withdrawing that amount");
      return false;
    }
  }
  console.log("Provided account was not an account with our bank");
  return false;
};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why checking the `instanceof`? If two banks share a compatible API you shouldn't block the transfers :P

Comment: ```instanceof``` being a simplified version of strictly ensuring API compatibility. I wouldn't want my money accidentally ending up in any old Object ;)

Comment: I see, yes, better be careful with your own money.